# SQL Query to append date (month/day) values with zero

Tags: mysql, sql, date, amazon-athena, presto

I have a dataset like this:

```
year | month | day | cust_id |
2018    9       7    xyz001
```

The problem with the dataset is that date is split into year, month and day.

When i use concat year, month and day i get the following result:

```
date:
201897
```

but i want something like this:

```
date:
20180907
```

that is, i want to add appending zeros to the month and day columns whenever we have single digit and leave the double digited values alone.

How can i do this in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You tagged this with `mysql` and `athena` (Presto). Do you need SQL that will  work unmodified in both databases?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `lpad()`.

```
SELECT concat(year, lpad(month, 2, '0'), lpad(day, 2, '0')) date
       FROM elbat;
```

However you should revise that design and just use a column of a date/time type.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert to a date in most databases with logic like this:

```
select cast(concat(year, '-', month, '-', day) as date)
```

Having a *bona fide* date may be sufficient.  Or you might want to convert back to a string, using an appropriate date format.  For instance, in MySQL you can use `date_format()`.

Answer (score 0):

In most SQL flavors you can use a case statement to apply logic (in this case prefix single digit date values with 0): http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

e.g.

```
select 
Year,
case
when len(month) = 2 then month
when len(month) = 1 then '0'+month else '' end as month,
case 
when len(day) = 2 then day
when len(day) = 1 then '0'+day else '' end as day
from table
```

I hope this helps show how to build case statements, then you can concatenate it all as follows:

```
select 
Year +
case
when len(month) = 2 then month
when len(month) = 1 then '0'+month else '' end +
case 
when len(day) = 2 then day
when len(day) = 1 then '0'+day else '' end +''+ as FullDate
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

select year + ' ' + month + ' ' + day

Comment: Not different from the question he posted up there